# Django TimeStamped mixin with different created/modified fields

Tags: python, django

Here is the classic mixin used to know when a Django object is created or modified:

```
class TimeStampable(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

The problem (it's not really a problem for most of us I guess) is that `created` and `modified` fields are not equal at the first creation (there is a tiny delta between them).

How would you improve this mixin to solve that specific issue?

I checked `django-model-utils` source code but found nothing.
I guess we would need to override `__init__` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 2 timezone objects to be equal, they must be created the exact same instance in time. That is virtually impossible, especially when you make the call to `timezone.now()` in series.

Essentially what happens at `TimeStampable` object creation time is that:

- `created` gets a `timezone.now` instance.
- `modified` gets a `timezone.now` which is created a tiny time fraction after the `created`'s one.

---

We can override model's `.save()` method to solve this problem:

We will use model's [`_state.adding()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/db/models/base.py#L481) method which is an instance of [`ModelState`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/db/models/base.py#L457), to define if an object is yet unsaved (newly created).

- If it is newly created, we need to take one (and only one) instance
  of `timezone.now` and pass it to `created` and `modified` fields.
- If the object just got modified, we must not forget to pass an instance of `timezone.now` to the `modified` field.

  ```
  class MyTimestampableModel(Timestampable):
      ...            

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          timezone_now = timezone.now()
          if self._state.adding:
              self.created = timezone_now
          self.modified = timezone_now
          super(MyTimestampableModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  ```